# Set the initial height of the Textarea as the last resize height

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

```
import { forwardRef, useEffect, useLayoutEffect } from 'react'
import { TextField, useTheme } from '@mui/material'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'

import { hexToRGBA } from 'src/@core/utils/hex-to-rgba'
import {
  getTextareaHeight,
} from 'src/store/academy/trainings'

const ResizableTextarea = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const markdownData = useSelector(getMarkdownData)
  const theme = useTheme()
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const currentIndex = useSelector(getCurrentIndex)
  const markdownHistory = useSelector(getMarkdownHistory)
  const textareaHeight = useSelector(getTextareaHeight)
  const undo = props.undoEvent
  const redo = props.redoEvent

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current.style.height = `${textareaHeight}px !important`
  }, [])

  return (
    <TextField
      inputRef={ref}
      aria-label='markdown area'
      placeholder='Markdown Text Editor'
      minRows={8}
      maxRows={8}
      id='outlined-textarea'
      multiline
      variant='outlined'
      value={markdownData}
      onChange={handleOnChange}
      sx={{
        width: '100%',
        maxWidth: '100% !important',
        minWidth: '100% !important',
        fontSize: '0.875rem',
        fontWeight: 400,
        lineHeight: 1.5,
        borderRadius: '6px',
        color: theme.palette.text.primary,
        background: theme.palette.background.paper,
        '&:hover': {
          borderColor: hexToRGBA(theme.palette.light.main, 0.35)
        },
        textarea: {
          // height: `${textareaHeight}px !important`,
          resize: 'vertical'
        }
      }}
    />
  )
})

export default ResizableTextarea
```

I have a component as above and I want to set the height value of the TextField in it:

```js
const markdownFieldRef = useResizeObserver(observerFunction)

function observerFunction(e, entry) {
  if (entry.contentRect.height >= 200) {
    dispatch(setTextareaHeight(entry.contentRect.height))
    e.height = entry.contentRect.height
  }
}
```

Function to the redux store as `textareaHeight`. Here is what I want: even if the component rerenders, I want it to start with the height `textareaHeight` because when I resize and change the textarea height, that height value becomes `textareaHeight`. But the problem is that the

```
minRows={8} maxRows={8}
```

It starts as `184px` because of the props.

I want to store resized textarea height

My custom useResizeObserver hook is:

```
import { useLayoutEffect, useRef } from 'react'

const useResizeObserver = callback => {
  const ref = useRef(null)

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const element = ref?.current

    if (!element) {
      return
    }

    const observer = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
      callback(element, entries[0])
    })

    observer.observe(element)
    return () => {
      observer.disconnect()
    }
  }, [callback, ref])

  return ref
}

export default useResizeObserver
```

Comment: Code Sandbox Link
https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-tom-4h2kxr?file=/src/components/Editor.jsx